# Making a class invisible

Tags: html, css, invisible

I'm want to have a div with class "a" to be invisible. I've tried already to give it the `display: none;` line in the CSS file but what it does is hide it, yet it doesn't catch any space and so all my other boxes don't stay in place.

Is there a way to do this using CSS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add `.a{visibility: hidden}` to your CSS. More about it here:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility

Answer (score 2):

`visibility:hidden` should hide the element, while keeping it's space so as not to move your other elements around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `visibility` css property. From sitepoint reference -

> This property specifies whether an
> element is visible—that is, whether
> the box(es) that are generated by an
> element are rendered.
>
> Note that even if a box in the normal
> flow is hidden, it still affects the
> layout of other elements, unlike the
> behavior that occurs when we suppress
> box generation altogether by setting
> display to none. Descendant boxes of a
> hidden box will be visible if their
> visibility is set to visible, whereas
> descendants of an element for which
> display is set to none can never
> generate boxes of their own.

More information can be found [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility).